# Pandoc won't process text italics in an mbox in math mode

Tags: math-mode, pandoc

I'm using pandoc to convert LaTeX to Word.  I represent certain concepts as multi-letter, italicized words.  I need to embed the same representations in some math.  xelatex has no problem with the following MWE.  `pandoc -o mwe.docx mwe.tex` converts the `mbox`ed text in the first instance, but refuses to process any of the italics commands inside `\mbox`.  (Adding additional braces doesn't help.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Let's apply $f$ to a {\em thing\/}, {\it things\/}, or \textit{more things}:
\[
    f(\mbox{thing})
\]
Oh, wait, forgot the italics:
\[
    f(\mbox{\em thing\/})
\]
\[
    f(\mbox{\it thing\/})
\]
\[
    f(\mbox{\textit{more things}})
\]
\end{document}
```

In each case, pandoc's error message points at the first backslash within the `\mbox`, and says something like:

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math 'f(\mbox{\textit{more things}})', rendering as TeX:
  f(\mbox{\textit{more things}})
          ^
  unexpected "\\"
  expecting "}", text, "{", "$", "$$", "\\(" or "\\["
```

I know that pandoc only converts a large subset of LaTeX.  Being able to handle a standard text font within an `\mbox` seems like a basic capability, but the error messages clearly suggest that including LaTeX commands within an mbox goes beyond what pandoc will do.  I'm using a version that I downloaded and installed last week:

```
pandoc 2.10.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.21, texmath 0.12.0.2, skylighting 0.8.5
```

I'm wondering if there is a pandoc trick or a LaTeX workaround that I could use.  Since the italicized words don't fundamentally represent mathematical concepts, I don't think it's appropriate to put them in math italics, would would look odd, anyway.  I'm open to any suggestion, however.

(The argument to a function doesn't have to be mathematical. Let the function be height-of, with people as arguments.  Don't ask me how to put a person between the parentheses, though.)

Comment: Hello, consider posting this into `pandoc` mailing list, maybe this is a use case which wasnt accounted for. `pandoc` has some specific math parsing settings, did you have tryed that? Workaround would be most likely writing your own filter, or find any fitting already written.

Comment: Btw. `\it` is depreciated for a very long time...

Comment: you do not say what you are generating with pandoc but if it is html+mathjax then mathjax 2 can't process text font changes, use \mathit )which is the text font, in math, nit the math italic font)

Comment: @DG, I know that `\em` and `\it` are considered deprecated by the cognoscenti, but I was being thorough. (For the record, I personally feel that the standard line--that we should use long multi-character commands for simple, common functions that have had short 2-character variants--is misguided, and I find it slightly annoying that any time one mentions a two-character italic or boldface command, one has to reminded that it is obsolete, deprecated, etc. I have used them for thirty years without problem, and I don't expect a future LaTeX to break all of the old documents that do the same.)

Comment: Thanks very much @TomášKruliš and @DavidCarlisle.  I didn't know about the `pandoc` list.  I'll try that if David's suggestion doesn't work.  David, it's MS Word that I unfortunately must generate. I didn't know that `\mathit` was text italic not math italic.  Very helpful.  The error message suggests it won't work, but I'll try it.

Comment: About my parenthetical comment above, I do know there are contexts where `\em` won't do what I expect.  In those contexts, I'll use something else.  Also for the record: I am very grateful that others think about the details of the many uses of LaTeX, so that I don't have to.  I know that there are needs that I have not (yet!) had, and that some of the standard guidelines are designed to address them.  I'm also grateful for all or the time that a handful of very knowledgeable people put into tex.SE.  It's really amazing and very helpful.  I have been around long enough to recognize the names.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, `\mathit` is a good solution to avoid the problem with pandoc.  Weirdly, it's producing roman text in math mode in my main document, though italic, as expected, in the MWE.  This is a different problem, obviously.

Comment: it is not that `\it` is "deprecated by the cognoscenti` it is simply not defined by default and has not been defined since 1994.  LaTeX does not define it. Some classes may define it for compatibility with LaTeX2.09 documents.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle.  I actually have never used `\it` until yesterday.  It's `\em` that I use routinely.  If that, too, is not defined by default, I'm surprised, since it has always worked.  (In my next project I may define a short macro abbreivation for `\emph` so I can avoid `\/` at the end, but I do not want to use anything as long as `\emph` for this purpose, and if forced to do so, I would be saddened.)  I really did include `\it` just to try everything pandoc.  I tried `\emph` in `\mbox` with pandoc, too, but thought that the example was long enough.

Comment: @Mars `\em` is defined by latex (but should almost never be used in math mode)

Comment: @Mars `\mbox{\em thing\/}` is logically wrong (you want italic not emphasis) and will not give italic in italic regions (such as theorems) and will not work in subscripts.  `\textit{thing}` or `\mathit{thing}` is shorter markup without any of those drawbacks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks. Yes, that makes sense.  `\mathit` turns out to be a good solution for math mode, and I just switched to `\textit` for the special terms in text mode.   In this case, I am generating the special terms with macros, so I don't care how verbose the formatting gets.  Now I have separate text mode and math mode macros, which is fine since I can maintain them in one place.  pandoc is happy now.  Thanks! (The problem I with `\mathit` generating roman text was specific to a particular typeface--seems like a bug--but I wasn't committed to using that typeface, and have switched.)